# Error 3265: Item not found in this collection"

Tags: ms-access, vba

> Error 3265: item not found in this collection

It exists! I checked. This simple module has worked for two years. Now, suddenly it doesn't:

```vb
Function AppendIndex()
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Set fld = DBEngine(0)(0).TableDefs("Submission_Key").CreateField("Index",dbLong)
    fld.Attributes = dbAutoIncrField
    DBEngine(0)(0).TableDefs("Submission_Key").Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I am guessing that there must be times when table `Submission_Key` doesn't exist, otherwise why would you have to keep adding the new field? What has changed? Are you running things in a different order?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Skippy. I'm actually thinking its a network issue. I ran the full program today and this module ran without errors. So when it can't "find" the table it's because of a network disruption. The can see the table in Access but the OLAP process cannot. This is one of those inaccurate errors that doesn't tell you the true cause.
Be well!